# Does CC-EV boost affect fuel consumption?

Tags: hill-climb-racing-2

I have often used the CC-EV boost on some *Hill Climb Racing 2* maps, but I'm not sure whether to use it in the adventure maps where fuel is needed. Does the CC-EV boost affect fuel consumption (i.e. use up fuel faster)?